# inherit autofac module in child lifetime scope

Tags: autofac

I have a module which does property injection for some particular type such as ILog.

```
protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration) 
{
        registration.Activated += [doing property injection];
}
```

It works fine within the same scope, but in a child scope, AttachToComponentRegistration won't be triggered anymore, I have to register the module again in order to enable property injection.

so my question is how to inherit registered module in child lifetime scope? or is there any other way to do this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterModule(new TestModule());
        builder.RegisterType<Test>().As<ITest>();
        var container = builder.Build();

        container.Resolve<ITest>().Say(); // output test11111

        var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope("nested", b =>
                                                            {
                                                                // b.RegisterModule(new TestModule());
                                                                b.RegisterType<Test2>().As<ITest2>();
                                                            });

        scope.Resolve<ITest>().Say();
        scope.Resolve<ITest2>().Say();
     }
}

public interface ITest
{
    void Say();
}

public class Test : ITest
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test1111111");
    }
}

public interface ITest2
{
    void Say();
}

public class Test2 : ITest2
{
    public void Say()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test2222222");
    }
}

public class TestModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, Autofac.Core.IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called for " + registration.Activator.LimitType);
        base.AttachToComponentRegistration(componentRegistry, registration);
    }
}
```

Comment: What Autofac version are you on?

Comment: There's an issue that may be relevant: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=218 ... also, can you please post the code that creates/registers components in the child scope? Thanks!

Comment: Nicholas, pls check out above source code, the "called for " doesn't appear for the nested scope components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug: 
http://code.google.com/p/autofac/issues/detail?id=218

You can find some workarounds there in discussion.